# Linux - Capture exit code of a ruby script

Tags: ruby, linux, bash

I have a simple ruby script which uses the `abort` function to exit with a `non-zero exit code`

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

puts "I ran"
abort "Exiting"
```

How can I capture the exit code when I execute this command in bash?

I have tried `exit_code=./test` or `exit_code=ruby test` to no avail.

Thanks

Comment: must be a duplicate ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
./test
echo $?
```

The special shell variable `$?` contains the exit code of the last terminated program.

It does not matter whether your program is a ruby program.  All Unix programs have an exit code which is handled alike in the starting shell.

Answer (score 2):

The exit code of the last program that ran is stored in `$?`

Answer (score 1):

You find the exit code from the previously executed command in the variable `$?`.